# Can I generate a service reference automatically for a REST WCF service?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, soap

The ONLY argument I can see for SOAP WCF over REST (json) wcf is the fact that once my service is created I can add a a reference in visual studio and I get a load of strongly typed classes ready for me and a client class that I can call all my webmethod through. It even sets up the web.config as far as I remember.

However when I expose a REST (json) service I still get a WSDL. So Im wondering is there still a way to build my references automatically?

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to the service the "old" way? [Code Table Example - Step 4](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/infinitydevguide/Subsystems/inwebapi-developer-help/Content/InfinityWebAPI/coCodeTableExampleBizOps.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Not using WCF tools. Unlike with SOAP (which has an established protocol for describing services - WSDL), REST doesn't. WADL is one such protocol, but it isn't too widespread and WCF does not support it. You still get a WSDL, because WCF will describe everything it can from the service. However, the WSDL won't have a `<wsdl:port>` element, which would describe the REST endpoint, which is why you get the WSDL, but cannot generate a reference to it.

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx has a lot more info on this issue.

Comment: Your example code in the linked thread is very helpful Carlos. Could I suggest you summarise here and include the code?

Comment: Expanded the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, newer answer.

today using openapi (swagger) I can achieve this by using [swagger inspector](https://inspector.swagger.io/builder) doing samples i can document my rest services as well as create a spec yml/json file allowing for validations and acceptance criteria as well as automated clients for java,python,c#,ruby,javascript and others I'm sure

Answer (score -1):

You can, indirectly. While the client generated by Visual Studio won't work, that client implements an interface, also generated, that you can use like this:

```
WebChannelFactory<IService> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IService>(new Uri(endpointAddress));

IService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

int result = proxy.Operation(1, 2, 3);
```

`WebChannelFactory` has another overload which accepts a `WebHttpBinding`, you can configure based on the service configuration, or you can make this configuration manually in your app.config file.

Answer (score -2):

I would like top elaborate:

Although it is true you cannot get a WSDL add service reference with a JSON REST WCF service, what I do is create two met data hooks:

1. is the operations returning JSON
2. is a single XML op returning a class wrapper which includes all the service classes I allow, I call it Discover:

i.e.

```
public class Discover
{
  public Manager Manager {get;}
  public Employee Emp {get;}
  ....
}

[OperationContract]
public Discover DiscoverDTOs()
```